# Understanding how javascript works when a parent function returns an inner function

Tags: javascript

I have an inner_function inside a parent_function.

I think I understand how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/93pp5/

```
 var text = 'Look at me';

function parent_function() {

  function inner_function() {
var scream = '!!!';
alert(text);
}

    inner_function();

};

parent_function();
```

However, I'm trying to figure out why my javascript below does not work. Can parent_function() not return inner_function()? My expectation was that calling parent_function() at the bottom would bring up an alert, but it does not: http://jsfiddle.net/93pp5/1/

```
var text = 'Look at me';

function parent_function() {

 return function inner_function() {
var scream = '!!!';
alert(text);
}

};

parent_function();
```

Comment: You have to execute the returned function `parent_function()();`

Comment: You are defining **two** functions, but I only see **one** function call. Logically, you need to have two function calls somewhere in your code if you defined two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `parent_function` returns a function which still needs to be called (executed).

```
var runAlert = parent_function();
// runAlert now holds the returned function but it still needs to be called to get the alert

runAlert(); // will alert
```